# Ibus-unikey not work

Tags: ibus

I'm has Insall and config Ibus-unikey[image]:

And change type Unikey :
[image]

But I'm can't type vietnamese, please help me!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try running `im-config` in a terminal, then continue until you can select the ibus option. (**this will allow to use ibus as imput method**). when finished, add `ibus-daemon -drx` to startup applications then restart your session and you should be able to use all the configuration you have made about ibus.

i recomend you to disable the app-laucher shortcut in order to use the switching shortcut for ibus.

Comment: I added ibus to system tray by dconf editor, sources [('xkb','jp'),('ibus','Mozc')], but instead of showing config icon in system try, the ibus config was at the cursor position. How can I config to move it to the system tray?